# First 1000 Prime Numbers with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I got program for Prime which gives only 2 as output. It should give me all based on java program I wrote.

Here is SQL I have created for Prime numbers. It is in SQL Server. I want to print first 1000 Prime numbers. Can you please let me know the issue in this code?

```
    DECLARE @i INT = 1
    DECLARE @j INT = 2
    DECLARE @COUNT INT
    BEGIN
    WHILE @j <= 10
        BEGIN
            SET @COUNT = 0
            WHILE @i <= @j
                BEGIN
                    BEGIN
                        IF((@j % @i) = 0)
                            SET @COUNT += 1
                    END
                    SET @i += 1
                END
            BEGIN
                IF (@COUNT = 2)
                    PRINT @j
            END
            SET @j += 1
        END
    END
    ;
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: Why would you want to do this in SQL Server..? It's probably one of the worst tools to calculate Prime numbers with. Certainly if you *were* to do it in SQL Server a `WHILE` is by far the most inefficient and a tally would likely be faster (but still, not what SQL Server is designed for).

Comment: FWIW, this statement `IF (@COUNT = 2)` is stopping your code.

Comment: @WEI_DBA why would that line stop the code?

Comment: @TabAlleman, I agree it shouldn't have, but when I tested it as is, it stopped and just printed `2`, but  then I commented out the `IF (@COUNT = 2)`, it printed 9 lines, 2 through 10.

Comment: Ah... Actually, it didn't stop the code.. It just printed `2` because of the `IF`. I was assuming it stopped.

Comment: Hello All 
No it will not stop the code  as "=" works as Assignment operator and also as a Comparison operator in SQL. 

When = used in SET it will work as assignment operator
And when = used in IF it will work as comparison operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question you asked:

> Can you please let me know the issue in this code?

The problem with your code is that you never reset `@i` back to 1 when you iterate to the next value of `@j`.

```
        ...
        END
        SET @i = 1   --add this line to fix it
        SET @j += 1
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the code but now have a different error. I can't concatenate these numbers and print it with space separated values.

Comment: `
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @j INT = 2
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @PRIME1000 AS varchar
BEGIN
WHILE @j <= 1000
    BEGIN
        SET @COUNT = 0
        WHILE @i <= @j
            BEGIN
                BEGIN
                    IF((@j % @i) = 0)
                        SET @COUNT += 1
                END
                SET @i += 1
            END
        BEGIN
            IF (@COUNT = 2)
            SET @PRIME1000 += (' ' + CAST(@j as varchar))
            PRINT @PRIME1000
        END
        SET @i = 1 
        SET @j += 1
    END
    PRINT @PRIME1000
END
;
`

Comment: @DigantJani it's too hard to read your code in the comment format.   Can you post it as a new question so that it can be formatted properly?

Answer (score 3):

For fun (and I feel like I've likely answered someone's homework, but hey...), like a said, a Tally would be far faster:

```
WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1,000 Numbers
Remainders AS(
    SELECT T1.I AS [Integer],
           T2.I AS Divider,
           T1.I % T2.I AS Remainder
    FROM Tally T1
         JOIN Tally T2 ON T1.I >= T2.I)
SELECT R.[Integer] AS PrimeNumber
FROM Remainders R
GROUP BY R.[Integer]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN R.Remainder = 0 THEN 1 END) <= 2
ORDER BY R.[Integer];
```

This is pretty fast when you do it for 1,000 rows, but (unsurprisingly) execution time starts to exponentially increase as you increase the range.

Comment: Good one!
if this is for homework then he will be lucky if he can explain what that stuff really does and how he found it as a personal solution loool

Comment: What is a "real time" @DigantJani?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar solution to Larnu's, but went into a meeting and didn't want it to go to waste. It produces 1229 prime numbers (all the prime numbers lower than 10,000), in 7 seconds.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally t
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM cteTally i
                WHERE t.n % i.n = 0
                AND i.n < t.n) = 1;
```

It can run a lot faster if we're allowed to use some hard-coded values.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(2),(3),(5),(7))x(n)
UNION ALL
SELECT n
FROM cteTally t
WHERE t.n % 2 <> 0
AND t.n % 3 <> 0 
AND t.n % 5 <> 0 
AND t.n % 7 <> 0 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM cteTally i
                WHERE t.n % i.n = 0
                AND i.n < t.n) = 1;
```

EDIT: The last version takes 1 second to find all the prime numbers below 10K, but goes up to 2.5 minutes to get all the prime numbers below 100K (9592 prime numbers).

EDIT 2:
Here's an option that combines both versions to improve performance on large data sets. It won't need a large tally table either.

```
DECLARE @j INT = 1;

CREATE TABLE #Primes( N int);
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WHILE @j <= 1000000
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Primes
        SELECT @J
        FROM #Primes
        WHERE @j % n = 0
        HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1;

        SET @j += 1;
    END;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SELECT * 
    FROM #Primes
    WHERE N <> 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH;

DROP TABLE #Primes;
GO
```

Comment: I was wondering why your dataset for 10,000 didn't have the same number of rows, but then realised you omitted 1 (I have 1,230 rows).

Comment: That's because [1 is not a prime number](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/why-isnt-1-a-prime-number/)

Comment: That article almost reads like a Joe Celko post at times, Luis. "1 isn't a number, it's a unit" is like hearing Joe say "An ID can't be an `integer` because it isn't a number; you don't do maths to it." 

Comment: They're both theorists so it makes sense. I didn't expect to see him mentioned here. But now I've realized who you are .

Answer (score 0):

This is your own code in the comment section of the solution proposed by @Tab Alleman with small modification to print the result as one string:

```
    DECLARE @i INT = 1
    DECLARE @j INT = 2
    DECLARE @COUNT INT
    DECLARE @PRIME1000 AS VARCHAR(1000)
    BEGIN
    WHILE @j <= 1000
        BEGIN
            SET @COUNT = 0
            WHILE @i <= @j
                BEGIN
                    BEGIN
                        IF((@j % @i) = 0)
                            SET @COUNT += 1
                    END
                    SET @i += 1
                END
            BEGIN
                IF (@COUNT = 2)
                    SET @PRIME1000 = CONCAT_WS(' ', @PRIME1000, @j)
            END
            SET @i = 1
            SET @j += 1
        END
    END;
    PRINT @PRIME1000
```